# seleccionar valores de una fila con el mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero extraer tres valores no consecutivos, de los cuales, uno de cada columna de una fila cualquiera. 
Los valores se muestran en una lista que provienen de una consulta hecha a una base de datos con el atributo POST. La selección la deseo hacer con onClick usando el mouse y no usar un botón (por fila o genérico). 
Creo haber usado la respuesta de uno de los expertos de este Blog que usó código javascript y funcionó, pero los valores se muestran en un alert y de ahí no he podido sacar esos valores para hacer la siguiente consulta.

A continuación muestro el código en Javascript:

```
var toma; $toma=""; 
$(document).ready(function() 
{ $(".alfa").click(function() 
{ var toma; $(this).parents("tr").find('#a2,#a4,#a6').each(function() 
{ toma+=$(this).html()+"\n"; }); alert(toma); }); 
});
```

Como se aprecia arriba, los tres valores a2, a4 y a6 (de un total de seis) están dentro de la variable, toma, que perfectamente muestra el valor de cada uno con el alert, pero no he podido rescatar discretamente cada valor para usarlo como entrada para otra consulta sin formulario.

NOTA: Deseo usar es el mouse con onClick. No quiero botones ni formularios.

Por favor, algun experto puede ayudar a resolver esta situación.

****************** COMENTARIOS DEL CODIGO REVISADO 16-09-2017 ******************

Saludos, en especial al Sr. Aaron Romero quien muy habilmente solucionó parte del problema que propuse hace unas 21 horas atras. El código del Sr. Romero efectivamente extrae los tres valores (no consecutivos) uno de cada columna 
como yo los requería; no obstante, cuando son varias filas (tengase presente 
que provienen de una BBDD y pueden ser centenares de filas) y haces click en cualquier fila el resultado es que se seleccionan todos los valores de esas 
tres columnas y en realidad lo que necesito es que con el onClick del mouse seleccione los tres valores de esas columnas, como lo está haciendo, pero sólo de esa fila que ha sido "clickeada".
Adjunto el código HTML que elaboré en base al del Sr.Romero para mostrar el resultado que arroja con dos filas:

............... HTML ........................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>peluca</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataGrid tr").on('click', function() {
        var toma1 = "", toma2 = "", toma3 = ""; 
         $("#dataGrid").find("tr").each(function() {
        toma1 += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
        toma2 += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
        toma3 += $(this).find('td:eq(4)').html();
      }); 

      //    $("#respuesta").text(toma1 + toma2 + toma3);

        $("#respuesta1").text(toma1);
        $("#respuesta2").text(toma2);
        $("#respuesta3").text(toma3);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="dataGrid">
     <tr id="f1">
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>fff</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="f2">
        <td>000</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>333</td>
        <td>444</td>
        <td>555</td>
    </tr>        
</table>

<!--  <label id="respuesta"></label>  -->

<label id="respuesta1"></label><br>
<label id="respuesta2"></label><br>
<label id="respuesta3"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

................ RESULTADO (se selecciona cualquier fila ....................

> aaa   bbb ccc ddd eee fff 000 111 222 333 444 555
>
> bbb111 ddd333 eee444

.....................  LO QUE ESPERO COMO RESULTADO .................

> // Se selecciona la fila f2
>
> 111 333 444
>
> Nota:
>
> // Se selecciona la fila f1
>
> bbb ddd eee

---

Agradecería que se pudiera adecuar el código a lo planteado.

Comment: Te aprovechas del jquery, te recomiendo aprender javascript puro

Answer (score 1):

Demoré un poco en entender lo que necesitas. 
Una muy buena opción de trabajar las celdas de las tablas es con el selector de posición "td:eq(posición)", de esta forma te olvidas de estar buscando los id's 
de cada celda.
De esta forma puedes tomar cada celda individualmente. Aún no se muy bien como quieres mostrar tu resultado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataGrid tr").on('click', function() {
        var toma1 = "", toma2 = "", toma3 = ""; 
         $("#dataGrid").find("tr").each(function() {
            toma1 += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
            toma2 += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
            toma3 += $(this).find('td:eq(5)').html();
          }); 
          $("#respuesta").text(toma1 + toma2 + toma3);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataGrid">
         <tr>
            <td>1111111</td>
            <td>222222</td>
            <td>3333333</td>
            <td>4444444</td>
            <td>55555555</td>
            <td>66666</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  
  <label id="respuesta"><label>
```

Comment: Excelente alternativa!!! Solo he ejecutado el código propuesto y funciona con la filosofía que planteo. Muy Bueno. Muchííísimas gracias Aaron, lo probaré. Atte. Peluca.

Comment: Solo como agregado, es de buena práctica usar los tag **thead, tbody** y **tfoot** en los **table**.